# URL redirect C# based on variable

Tags: c#, url-routing

I don't work with C# so please forgive my ignorance.

Currently have this:

///// Layout /////

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Help", "Help", new { controller = "Help", topic = ViewBag.Topic }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

//// Controller Help /////

```
 @if (Request.QueryString.GetValues(0)[0] == "Dash")
 { 
     //HTML code 
 }
 @if (Request.QueryString.GetValues(0)[0] == "Manage")
 {
     //HTML code2
 }
```

From what I understand, the `@Html.ActionLink` is pulling a query into the "Help" controller and thus rendering HTML code (internal link) and page based on the topic.

Is there a simple way to turn that into an external URL instead. Thus @if="dash" then url="www.foo.com" instead of HTML code.

Best other option if this is not possible? The key aspect is that each page topic needs to create a URL link to a different page.

Comment: the actionlink generates HTML <a> tag that points to the controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many topics I find that the current approach is more clear and easy to mantain, maybe you could change those @if...@if to a if/else-if and store that first parameter of the querystring into a variable

```
@{ 
    String topic ;

    topic = Request.QueryString.GetValues(0)[0] ;

    if (topic.Equals("Dash"))
    { 
        //HTML code 
    }
    else if (topic.Equals("Manage"))
    {
        //HTML code2
    }
}
```